# Configure Asp.net Telerik editor Dialog when EnableEmbededScript is OFF

Tags: asp.net-ajax, telerik, telerik-editor

I have used asp.net Telerik RadEditor control in web-site and to host this website in Shared hosting server, I have to disable `Telerik.EnableEmbeddedScripts` flag and add required scripts in page but Dialog of RadEditor is not working.

My site is hosted in FastHost shared hosting server. Other controls of Telerik is worked perfect. Version of Telerik is 2011.3.1115.35

Can anyone suggest how to enable dialogs for editor control on any shared hosting server?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to test with enabled CDN scripts or configure your own custom CDN provider which will [automatically import the dialog scripts](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/cdn-custom-provider.html)

If you disable the scripts, you will need to create a handler file [EditorDialogScripts.zip](http://www.telerik.com/ClientsFiles/85bd9dee-7a45-4048-b926-9f0eafd80445_258584-EditorDialogScripts.zip) - this file is old and created for Q1 SP2 2009) containing the dialog scripts of RadEditor and import it via the DialogsScriptFile property of RadEditor (`DialogsScriptFile="~/Scripts/EditorDialogScripts.ashx"`), which is a time consuming and not straightforward process.

You can see which files are loaded in the dialogs using Firebug or Fiddler.